Magnetic Background Field Correction Methods for ground surveys to detect anomalies
For magnetic ground surveys, I would like to subtract the regional magnetic field, to have an anomaly distribution.
What are the most sophisticated ways to do so, except than simply subtracting the moving average of each shifted window?
I saw some methods using spherical Gaussian and Tinkarov...
I don't need to implement those by myself, if they are already implemented, the better!!!
I appreciate any help!
Regards!

What is spherical Gaussian and Tinkarov?
